# Query is taking more time in db, although used indexed columns in join conditions then what can we do in code to Optimize

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, query-optimization

If a query is taking more time in db even after using indexed columns in join conditions then what can we do in code to minimize the execution time in Oracle and MySql.

I am feeling some daily in execution of query in Oracle from Java layer. Although I am using condition on the query on index column on numeric value column.
I am using Java Prepared Statement and execution executed from Java.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` in Mysql or `EXPLAIN PLAN` in Oracle to see details on the query execution. There you can see which indices are used. Your question is far to general to give you a better recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking us to diagnose something without symptoms. You should provide output of EXPLAIN PLAN (or set autotrace on) and also the schema in question.

There is more to tuning than indexing columns. But without knowing, and I assume you've done all the optimization you can do, then it may be time to do pre-calculation with either tables, or materialized views.

Other options include solid state disk or parallelism (partitioning and/or parallel query) and so forth.

Not sure what you mean by "Java layer", I find that Java is often a hindrance to performance in Oracle. Stick with PL/SQL for stored procedures and daily jobs, if possible. To a Java programmer, every problem appears to be a Java problem. But Java brings little to the table as far as speeding up queries.